# Own variables in Netlogo

Tags: variables, vector, netlogo

I am creating own variables for a breed in Netlogo 5.10. However, I dont know if it is possible to define a vector or a matrix for each agent. For the moment i am creating as n variables for the vector size.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [other ways](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/arraystables.html) to do this, but the canonical way to represent collections of data in NetLogo is [lists](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists). A numerical vector would be a simple list of numbers; a matrix could be a list of lists.

Look at the **Lists** section in the [NetLogo dictionary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html) to get an overview of the wonderful things you can do with lists.

Comment: Gorillaz Fan, just to clarify Nicolas's answer in case it's not obvious: NetLogo variables can hold any kind of NetLogo data.  So a single `-own` variable can contain a list.  Just use `set` to assign a list to that variable.